# Application or object defined error in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

As you saw from the title I am getting error 1004.  I am trying to make it iterate through cells B4 to B9 and at each one and if there is no sheet with the name in that cell it creates it and pastes the headers that are on the data entry page (C1:M3) and the data on that row from C to I onto the newly created sheet. If it does exist it looks at A1 of the sheet with that name and pastes the data into column B and the row that A1 specifies. And it does this for B4:B9 on each cell. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Function copyHeader(inputrange As String, inputsheet As String, outputcell As String, outputsheet As String)
    Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange).Copy Destination:=Sheets(outputsheet).Range(outputcell)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Cells(1, 1).Value = 4  'probably better to make this dynamic
End Function

Function copyDetail(inputrange As String, inputsheet As String, outputcell As String, outputsheet As String)
    Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange).Copy Destination:=Sheets(outputsheet).Range(outputcell)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Cells(1, 1).Value = 4  'probably better to make this dynamic
End Function

Function createTab(tabname As String)
    Worksheets.Add.Name = tabname
End Function

Function shtExists(shtname As String) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Set sht = Sheets(shtname)
    shtExists = True
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        shtExists = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function lastCell(Col As String)
    With ActiveSheet
        lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Sub AddData()
    Dim teamname As String
    Dim countery As Integer
    Dim teamdata As String
    Dim matchcounter As String
    Dim resp As Boolean
    Dim maxCounter As Integer

    counter = 4
    maxCounter = lastCell("B")

    On Error GoTo eh
    For counter = 4 To maxCounter
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry").Select
        teamdata = "C" & counter & ":" & "N" & counter
        teamname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry").Range("B" & counter).Value

    resp = shtExists(teamname)

    If resp = False Then
        createTab (teamname)

        copyHeader "C1:M3", "DataEntry", "B1", teamname
        matchcounter = CStr(Sheets(teamname).Range("A1").Value)
        copyDetail teamdata, "DataEntry", "B" & matchcounter, teamname

    ElseIf resp = True Then
        copyDetail teamdata, "DataEntry", "B" & matchcounter, teamname
    End If
    Next counter

Worksheets("DataEntry").Activate
Done:
    Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Source
End Sub
```

Here is what my data entry sheet looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYo0P.png

Here is what the sheets that I am creating for each team look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaBfX.png

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? If you comment (or otherwise remove) the error handler, what does it show you?

Comment: You REALLY should help us out by noting the line where the error occurs.  However, I get your error on line 'createTab (teamname)' if sheet(teamname) doesn't exist.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: I get the error when the if statement that handles sthexists() equals true

Comment: Please pay attention to detail - it really matters!  You have NO routine named 'sthexists'  it is 'shtexists'

Comment: Not sure what your data looks like, but if appropriate, change your ".Paste" to ".PasteSpecial xlPasteValues"

Comment: To prevent any accidental typos causing issues (like the one @WayneG.Dunn points out), you should add `Option Explicit` to the very top (above even `Sub myroutine()`) to make sure you explicitly declare all variables used. This would have prompted you to that `sthexists` doesn't exist.

Comment: `CopyHeader` and `CopyDetail` should probably be subs, since they don't return values and they're changing data on the sheet.

Comment: sorry 'sthexists()' should be shtexists() that was a typo in my comment not in the actual code

Comment: @CLR I changed those functions to subs and took out the error handler and it is saying that the problem is with the first line of copyDetail()

    Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange).Copy Destination:=Sheets(outputsheet).Range(outputcell)

When it is being called in this part of the code near the bottom:




    ElseIf resp = True Then
        Call copyDetail(teamdata, "DataEntry", "B" & matchcounter, teamname)
    End If

Comment: Did you try the 'PasteSpecial...' I suggested earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mocked this up here and tweaked your code to get it working. It isn't necessarily how I'd do it normally, (I wouldn't bother storing the destination row in A1 for instance - I'd detect the bottom and add there) but it works and should

a) make sense to you and

b) work with your data structure.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyHeader(inputrange As String, inputsheet As String, outputcell As String, outputsheet As String)
    Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange).Copy Destination:=Sheets(outputsheet).Range(outputcell)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Cells(1, 1).Value = 4  'probably better to make this dynamic
End Sub

Sub copyDetail(inputrange As String, inputsheet As String, outputcell As String, outputsheet As String)
    Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange).Copy Destination:=Sheets(outputsheet).Range(outputcell)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets(outputsheet).Cells(1, 1).Value = Sheets(outputsheet).Cells(1, 1).Value + 1
End Sub

Sub createTab(tabname As String)
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = tabname
End Sub

Function shtExists(shtname As String) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Set sht = Sheets(shtname)
    shtExists = True
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        shtExists = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function lastCell(sht As Worksheet, Col As String)
    With sht
        lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Sub AddData()
    Dim teamname As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim teamdata As String
    Dim matchcounter As String
    Dim resp As Boolean
    Dim maxCounter As Integer
    Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet
    counter = 4
    Set sourcesheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry")
    maxCounter = lastCell(sourcesheet, "B")

    On Error GoTo eh
    For counter = 4 To maxCounter
        sourcesheet.Select
        teamdata = "C" & counter & ":" & "N" & counter
        teamname = sourcesheet.Range("B" & counter).Value

    resp = shtExists(teamname)

    If resp = False Then
        createTab (teamname)

        copyHeader "C1:M3", sourcesheet.Name, "B1", teamname
        matchcounter = CStr(Sheets(teamname).Range("A1").Value)
        copyDetail teamdata, sourcesheet.Name, "B" & matchcounter, teamname

    ElseIf resp = True Then
        matchcounter = CStr(Sheets(teamname).Range("A1").Value)
        copyDetail teamdata, sourcesheet.Name, "B" & matchcounter, teamname
    End If
    Next counter

Worksheets("DataEntry").Activate
Done:
    Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Source
End Sub
```